# Rake abort! while trying to read email from gmail server using IMAP

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, redmine, bitnami

I am running below rake command to read email using IMAP from use_redmine.bat in which my working directory is \Bitnami\redmine-3.4.2-0\apps\redmine\htdocs> and the command is

```
CALL C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.2-0\scripts\setenv.bat
cd C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.4.2-0\apps\redmine\htdocs
CALL rake redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=imap.gmail.com port=993 ssl=SSL username=xxxxx@gmail.com password=xxxxx project_from_subaddress=xxxxx@gmail.com tracker=bug allow_override=project,tracker,priority
```

My redmine installed in windows and used pycron to execute the above command every minute.
But responded to the error on ssl

```
rake aborted!
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: For the usual suspects... use TLS 1.0 (or above) and [Server Name Indication (SNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). Otherwise, you need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `ssl=SSL` by `ssl=1`

*[Edited]*

It has now been documented at 
https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/redmine/#how-to-convert-incoming-email-to-issues-in-redmine